# Does an application need app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

Previously sorry for my English...
I want to store connection string in app.config

Does my application need app.config file after it have build
I've tried to delete app.config and then ran application from the release folder but no errors appeared, but when from the debug folder i have got one.

So where app.config's keys embed in application?

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you build; the app.config is renamed to `<YourAssembly>.exe.config` and copied to the output directory.

This is why it works even if you deleted app.config - the old .config is still in the output directory. Try looking in that directory for a .config file.

Comment: Yes you are right.
I want to use bitbucket.org (i know it offers private repos, but... i want so) to host my sources that have secret info in connection string. And i think how to solve this problem, where should i store connection strings preferably.